# SImplifying inequalities

Tags: inequality

I understand that the inequality $-3\lt-x-2\lt 3$ can simplify to $-1\lt x \lt 5$ by first factoring out the negative from the center, reversing the inequalities, and carrying out opposite operations to isolate 'x'.
What I don't understand is why you get a different answer when first adding a constant before reversing the signs.

Ex.

1. $-3\lt-x-2\lt3$
2. $-1\lt-x\lt 5$
3. $-5\lt x\lt1$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: If we multiply with a negative number , ">" turns into "<" and vice versa.

Comment: As @Peter said, this rule only applies to variables when multiplying by a negative number.

Comment: "I understand that the inequality $-3\lt-x-2\lt 3$ can simplify to $-1\lt x \lt 5$" : No.  As per the other comments, instead $$-3 < (-x-2) < 3 \iff -1 < \color{red}{-x} < 5.$$

Comment: Thanks! My original premise was in error - the problem actually began with $-3\lt-(x-2)\lt3$ - I omitted the parentheses in my work which resulted in the error!